# How to format vertically with GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout, boxlayout

I am making a project that uses a box and a `JComboBox` and want to use `GridBagLayout`. I want the combo box at the top center of the screen, then the `Box` with a `JTextArea` inside at the center. This is my code so far:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

/**comboBoxFrame Constructor
 * Takes Mouse Event Input From User
 * Based On Option Chosen By User From Dropdown, Displays Corresponding information, Taken From birtdayCaclulator.java
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class comboBoxFrame extends JFrame {
    private final JComboBox<String> classComboBox;
    private JTextArea outputBox;
    
    private static final String[] names = {
            "-Select-",
            "Age Summary",
            "Zodiac Sign",
            "Birth Stone",
            "Generation",
            "Day of Week", 
            "Lucky Number",
            "Milestones", 
            "First Presidential Election Vote",
            "Days Since Last Birthday",
            "Days Until Next Birthday",
            "Animal Years Summary",
            "Other Planet Age Summary",
            "Days After Milestones Summary",
            "Birthday Summary",
            "Help"
    };
    private static final String[] output = {
            "Output will appear here",
            CreateDriver.bday.ageSummary(),
            CreateDriver.bday.getZodiacSign(),
            CreateDriver.bday.getBirthStone(),
            CreateDriver.bday.getGeneration(),
            CreateDriver.bday.getDayOfWeek(),
            CreateDriver.bday.getLuckyNum(),
            CreateDriver.bday.getMileStones(),
            CreateDriver.bday.getFirstPresElectionVote(),
            CreateDriver.bday.getDaysSinceLastBday(),
            CreateDriver.bday.getDaysTillNextBday(),
            CreateDriver.bday.animalYearsSummary(),
            CreateDriver.bday.otherPlanetAgeSummary(),
            CreateDriver.bday.getDaysAfterMilestonesSummary(),
            CreateDriver.bday.toString(),
            CreateDriver.bday.getHelp()
    };
    
    public comboBoxFrame() {
        super("Birthday Calculator");
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        
        Box box = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);    
        outputBox = new JTextArea("Output will appear here", 20, 50);
        box.add(outputBox, gbc);
        
        classComboBox = new JComboBox<String>(names);
        classComboBox.setMaximumRowCount(5);
                
        classComboBox.addItemListener(
            new ItemListener() {
                @Override
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
                    if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                        outputBox.setText(output[classComboBox.getSelectedIndex()]);
                    }
                }
            }
        );
        
        add(classComboBox, gbc);
        outputBox = new JTextArea("Output will appear here");
        add(outputBox, gbc);
    }
}
```

It currently prints the ComboBox and Box next to each other at the center Y Axis. Does anyone know what I should change to fix this?

Comment: *Does anyone know what I should change to fix this?* - Did you even search the site (or the web for examples using a GridBagLayout? The code you posted would indicate you did not. You need to actually set the `GridBagConstraints` to meaningful values. Specifically the `gridy` constraint. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)  for working examples. Next time do some basic searching for examples BEFORE posting a question. Also, why are you using a Box? I don't see why it is needed.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Limit `names` to just two entries and remove the `output` array which is irrelevant to the layout problem. 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.